# How to get the correct sql select function for the following task

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to display the total sales of 2014 for each car brand on the following webpage:

`http://test.com/example/2014/8`.

**htaccess file:**

```
RewriteRule ^example/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ test?year=$1&monthnumber=$2 [L,QSA]
```

**Example data (carbrand, year, monthnumber, sales):**

```
carbrand  year  month  sales
----------------------------
Mercedes  2014     8    2800
BMW       2014     8    3000
Audi      2014     8    2700
Mercedes  2014     7    2600
BMW       2014     7    2900
Audi      2014     7    2400
```

**Html/php:**

```
<?php
    $year= $_GET['year'];
    $monthnumber= $_GET['monthnumber'];
```

**(Now the tricky part)**

```
    $sql = "SELECT ........
```

I need the `sql select` function to do 3 things:

- step 1: find all different car brands that sold vehicles in 2014 => SELECT distinct carbrand FROM `example-table` WHERE year = :year
- step 2: calculate the total sales for each of those distinct car brands in that year => select "SUM(sales)) for each car brand" WHERE year = :year
- step 3: order the results by those total sales, desc => ORDER BY "SUM(sales) for each car brand" DESC

  ```
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(":year", $year);
  $stmt->execute();

  if($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
  ?>

  <?php echo $result['carbrand'];?> <?php echo $result['(sum sales for that brand in a given year'];?>

  <?php
  }// end if
  else {
  echo '0 results';
  }// end else
  ?>
  ```

The result of my example should be:

- BMW, 5900
- Mercedes, 5400
- Audi, 5100

I can't figure out how to write the correct sql function that gives me these results. More specifically I don't get how I can include the distinct car brands in step 2 and step 3.

Can anyone help me out with this sql function?

Comment: Read about the GROUP BY facility of SQL

Comment: Without table layout/data, there's no way to give an accurate answer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your considerations were nearly right. Only the first one "Distinct" was wrong.
As pointed out in the comments, you should use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
    carbrand,
    SUM(sales) totals
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    year = 2014
GROUP BY
    carbrand
ORDER BY
    totals DESC
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f3d42/1)

If you're using aggregate functions like i.e. SUM() you nearly ever want to GROUP your data. Because of that you find these functions in the chapter [Functions and Modifiers for Use with GROUP BY Clauses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help and the code/demo! I understand the "Group by" function now.